# C using fstat() to read size of file

Tags: c, file

I consider reading file of unknown size that I know doesn't change size in the meantime. So I intend to use `fstat()` function and `struct stat`. Now I am considering what the `st_size` field really means and how should I use it.

If I get the file size's in this way, then allocate a buffer of that size and read exactly that size of bytes there seems to be one byte left over. I come to this conclusion when I used `feof()` function to check if there really nothing left in `FILE *`. It returns false! So I need to read `(st_size + 1)` and only than all bytes have been read and `feof()` works correctly. Should I always add this +1 value to this size to read all bytes from binary file or there is some hidden reason that this isn't reading to **EOF**?

```
struct stat finfo;
fstat(fileno(fp), &finfo);
data_length = finfo.st_size;
```

I am asking about this because when I add `+1` then the number of bytes read by `fread()` is really `-1` byte less, and as the last byte is inserted `00` byte. I could also before checking with `feof()` do something like this

```
fread(NULL, 1, 1, fp);
```

It is the real code, it is a little odd situation:

```
// reading png bytes from file
    FILE *fp = fopen("./test/resources/RGBA_8bits.png", "rb");

    // get file size from file info
    struct stat finfo;
    fstat(fileno(fp), &finfo);
    pngDataLength = finfo.st_size;

    pngData = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*pngDataLength);
    if( fread(pngData, 1, pngDataLength, fp) != pngDataLength) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Incorrect number of bytes read from file!\n", __func__);
        fclose(fp);
        free(pngData);
        return;
    }

    fread(NULL, 1, 1, fp);
    if(!feof(fp)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Not the whole binary file has been read.\n", __func__);
        fclose(fp);
        free(pngData);
        return;
    }

    fclose(fp);
```

Comment: No, if the length of a a file has 1000 bytes, it's 1000 bytes, not 1001 nor 999.

Comment: Please show your code if you want more detailed answers.

Comment: now it works but I have to add this fread(NULL, 1, 1, fp); I can also change pngDataLength +1 in the first fread() but it returns just pngDataLength

Comment: `fread(NULL, 1, 1, fp);` doesn't make sense, what are you expecting this to do ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: `fread(NULL, 1, 1, fp);` make sense it set `feof()` in the way it return `EOF` that I have correctly read all bytes from the file

Comment: With `fread(NULL, 1, 1, fp);`, and code has not all ready read all the data, then code attempts to save a byte into `NULL`, which is UB.  So anything may happen, even appear like no data was read.  IOWs, do not code `fread(NULL, 1, 1, fp);`.  Instead suggest `if (fgetc(fp) != EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is normal.

`feof` will return true only once you have tried to read beyond the file's end which you don't do as you read exactly the size of the file.

Comment: ok thx so it will be set only after failed read and not is checking that in advance that the next read fail. :)